# The webview doesn't Display url

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

My web url is loading in all iPhone devices, but it shows a blank white screen on iPad. Here is my code.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: [@"http://tawk.to/da4134baa860e706d766f456b5fceddb12f9be29/popout/default?$_tawk_popout=true&$_tawk_sk=581abfe08759b753e4a93f46&$_tawk_tk=226e0dafe1b8741a1bec1cbdf29607b9&v=518" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

SVWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: what is the super class of SVWebViewController ?It seems a controller not a uiWebView.

Comment: @Sommm SVWebViewController is subclass of uiviewcontroller. inside SVWebViewController i take UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is running on iPhone, we can assume it is correct. 
I suggest you focus on the handling of the iPad screen routines. I expect an error in that part.

Comment: Size is whatever but need to display its content. if i am loading url like 'www.google.com' then its open perfect.

Comment: Again, you say it's okay on iPhone. So the loading routine is okay. However it is not displayed okay on iPad. That means that your code to display it on iPad are wrong. You shall look into that part of your code. Probably constraints/size settings/refresh etc.

Answer (score 0):

IN your SVWebViewController, add UIwebview and hooked up its property.

```
NSURL *url_TAC=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://tawk.to/da4134baa860e706d766f456b5fceddb12f9be29/popout/default?$_tawk_popout=true&$_tawk_sk=581abfe08759b753e4a93f46&$_tawk_tk=226e0dafe1b8741a1bec1cbdf29607b9&v=518"];

NSURLRequest *request_TAC=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url_TAC];
[_webView_TAC loadRequest:request_TAC];
```

Comment: I already used code as above and works for iphone but specifically ipad display white screen.